# npm throws error on a newly created react app on npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a newly created react-app and on my first npm start it throws an unhandled error.

```
Starting the development server...

node:events:342
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/bin/firefox ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /usr/bin/firefox',
  path: '/usr/bin/firefox',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]
```

I don't have any dependencies as of now but i don't get what is causing this error. But the dev server starts with
**sudo npm start**

Comment: Please refer a node version & npm version info.

Comment: check the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70182608/i-am-trying-to-run-npm-start-in-my-terminal-but-it-isnt-working/70182990#70182990

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of a permission error , please uninstall existing nodejs, npm and try to install nodejs using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) it will help you to overcome permission issues in npm