# I am trying to run npm start in my terminal, but it isn't working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-start

I am trying to run `npm start` to begin a new React Project and it is not working. I have done this many times, but now I get the following error:

```
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/EgorUlybin/Desktop/Programming/practice folder/React/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.2.0
EgorUlybin@MacBook-Pro routing %
```

In the browser, the error message that I get is:

> The site can't be reached
> localhost refused to connect.

Comment: please share your package.json file here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's might be because of NodeJS version.

Downgrade your NodeJS version from **Current (17)** to **LTS (16)** version by nvm.

Comment: I just installed v.16 of node.js and it works! Why is it that v.17 is not working?

Comment: I suppose to in newer version has some dependency issue and block some requirements. So make sure to always use LTS version while creating real time applications.

Comment: I've tried using versions 16.13.1 and 14.18.1 and still I get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack to fix this issue.

Simply create a new react app using `yarn create-react-app my-app`, then copy the `node_modules` folder and replace your previous React app `node_modules` file with it.