# new computer but react isnt working as normal

Tags: reactjs, startup

I have a problem, I just got a new computer and I installed node js, git for windows, and visual studio, then I created a react app with the `npx create-react-app`. command and all seemed fine, but I discovered that I cannot create a development server with the `npm run start` command, it says the reason is unsupported.

I've tried restarting the computer but nothing works

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2k0b.png)

**kind regards**

Christian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: You can check same issue with solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70182608/i-am-trying-to-run-npm-start-in-my-terminal-but-it-isnt-working/70182990#70182990

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be because of the node version you are using is not supported by your machine ( 17+)

**Solution -1**

Try using node version 16

1. Uninstall Node.js from the computer.
2. Download Node.js version 16 and install it again

Same problem is described here

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063

**Solution -2**

In your package.json: change this line

"start": "react-scripts start"

to

"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"

**Solution -3**

Or you can use yarn to create and run react project

Yarn. yarn create react-app my-app. ...
npm start or yarn start. Runs the app in development mode. ...
npm test or yarn test. ...
npm run build or yarn build.

I hope this might solve your problem